# Is Twilight Company in "Rogue One"?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the film, we see a detachment of soldiers accompany the main characters to Scarif (this is seen in the trailers so no spoiler).

It is somewhat difficult to understand the names of the various soldiers, although it seems clear that Cassian Andor and Bodhi Rook say the names several of them. Given that the Lucasfilm Story Group is attempting to create a unity between the various media outlets (books, comics, etc...) and that the book "**Star Wars: Battlefront - Twilight Company**" is indeed part of the new canon, is there any confirmation given in the film that this group of rebel soldiers is in some way connected to or is Twilight Company?

Comment: Not a full confirmation in-universe, but the official novelization is written by Freed, who is indeed Star Wars: Battlefront: Twilight Company author.

Comment: So far, none of the main characters names' is in the novelization text

Comment: “this is seen in the trailers so no spoiler” — _NOT ALL OF US WATCH TRAILERS, YOU SCRUFFY-LOOKING SPOILER-MERCHANT_

Comment: Who's scruffy looking?! Not spoiling a trailer (especially after the movie has opened) seems to be well outside the bounds of spoiler statute of limitation you small-eared gundark ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

You're likely referring to this line from the film:

> **Cassian:** Melshi, Pao, Baze, Chirrut, you'll take main squad, move east and get wide of the ship.
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story* (2016)</sup>

But Melshi and Pao are identified in the *Rogue One Visual Guide* as members of Alliance Special Forces, rather than the infantry grunts seen in Twilight:

[image]

> At Captain Andor's orders, SpecForces Infiltrator Sergeant Ruescott Melshi is placed in command of the Pathfinders that infiltrate the Imperial compound on Scarif.

[image]

> After sneaking onto Scarif in an Imperial shuttle, Pao and his fellow SpecForce commandos hide in the jungle canopy.

Several other members of the infiltration team are named in the *Visual Guide*:

- Arro Basteren
- Farsin Kappehl
- Walea Timker
- Jav Mefran
- Stordan Tonc
- Eskro Casrich
- Yosh Calfor
- Rodma Maddel
- Taidu Sefla
- Serchill Rostok

All of these (except for Maddel, who's an intelligence scout) are explicitly identified as SpecForces operatives, not the sort of people we'd expect to find in Twilight.

What's more, the novel *Twilight Company* reveals that Twilight was some distance away from the events of *A New Hope*, which occurred [only shortly after](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147586/31051) the events of *Rogue One*:

> Private Hazram Namir had been in his bunk disassembling and reassembling a DLT-20A blaster rifle when word about Alderaan came down.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Days later, when word came of the destruction of the Empire's planet-razing battle station, Namir was manning a trench in the honey fields of Vir Apshire.
>
> <sup>*Battlefront: Twilight Company* Chapter 32</sup>

Considering this, it's doubtful that Twilight was present at Scarif.

Comment: ah brilliant - it's been a while since I've read Twilight Company and forgot it covered ANH and ESB

Answer (score 2):

Spoiler from Rogue One

> My impression from the movie (I have not read the novelization) is that there were almost no Rebel survivors from the battles in the Scarif system.  The mortality rate for those who had made it through the planetary shield (ground forces and fighter craft) was 100%.  The ship carrying the plans may have carried away the entirety of the survivors, and all those except R2D2 and C3PO were captured or killed shortly after.  EDIT: Upon reflection, there were slightly more survivors.  Red Leader and Gold Leader (and parts of their squadrons) did survive to fly against the Death Star in Episode IV.